# Broadcast user information before connection

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I would like to know if it is possible to broadcast data even before having a bluetooth connection.

The objective is to when searching for nearby devices that are using this same app, a profile picture and user name will appear even before connecting. Is that possible? If so, how?

Edit: If not possible, is there a workaround or trick to do this? I was thinking of when the BroadcastReceiver finds a new device we connect to it, get that data, and disconnect. But I don't know if this is possible either nor how to do it properly.

Comment: I don't think it's possible.

Comment: I think you can cache the details from  the devices you have connected earlier.